# MomentJS: how to get last month date (not start of the month)?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using `MomentJS` to handle dates in my project.
I need to get last month date starting from current date.

I mean if today is 6th April, when I click on some button I should get a period between 7th March and 6th April. The same should happen if, for example, today is 15th March: in this case I should get a period that is between 16th February and 15th March.

I read the MomentJS documentation and I found these methods:

```
moment().subtract(1,'months');

moment().subtract(30, 'days');
```

As you can see they can't suit for my needs.

Any idea?

Comment: According to this algorithm, if today is 31 March then it should return 1 March. Is that expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add 1 day onto your result if you're wanting the day after the day exactly 1 month ago:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'month').add(1, 'day');
```

---

```js
console.log("Today:", moment().format("Do MMMM"));
console.log("Month ago:", moment().subtract(1, 'month').add(1, 'day').format("Do MMMM"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Would try `moment().subtract(1, 'months').add(1, 'days')`.